# What software recommendation for designing human faces?

Tags: windows, graphic-design

Either Adobe Photoshop or Illustrator for realistic appearance of human face designs drawn with a tablet pen? Maybe drawing it on paper, later scanning it and bringing it to Illustrator for modifications and colouring. 
My operating system is Windows, the price range does not matter that much.

Comment: What exact features are you expecting from such a program?

Comment: I would like to draw the face on paper, then scan it and render it to illustrator through a graphic pen. My question is which software is more appropriate for doing so? And all that includes the lighting and shades? Which software is better for this? Can it be done in Photoshop?

Comment: Hi Andra!  Welcome!  Please update your question to include the relevant information.  Please also specify the operating system(s) and price range (or gratis).  Thanks!